# Setting up Apache subdirectory alias with Firefly III

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, nginx

I am trying to setup [Firefly III](https://firefly-iii.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/server.html) in a subdirectory of my web server. In other words: I'd like to access it via `https://www.example.com/firefly` instead of being at the root.

Here's my Apache SSL config:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/srv/http"
  Alias /firefly/ "/srv/firefly/public/"
  <Directory "/srv/firefly/public/">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This seems to work, but the site (correctly) redirects to a login page, `example.com/firefly/login` and this 404s:

```
192.168.1.1 - - [20/Feb/2019:21:57:18 -0500] "GET /firefly/ HTTP/1.1" 302 400
192.168.1.1 - - [20/Feb/2019:21:57:18 -0500] "GET /firefly/login HTTP/1.1" 404 1012
```

As I understand it, `/login` is a custom route that should be handled by the PHP application, but I do not know how to make it play nice with my alias.

There are [some nginx instructions for setting firefly up in a subdirectory](https://firefly-iii.readthedocs.io/en/latest/support/faq.html#i-am-using-nginx-and-want-to-expose-firefly-iii-under-budget):

```
location ^~ /firefly-iii/ {
   deny all;
}

location ^~ /budget {
   alias /var/www/firefly-iii/public;
   try_files $uri $uri/ @budget;

   location ~* \.php(?:$|/) {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
      fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true; #Avoid sending the security headers twice
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
   }
}

location @budget {
   rewrite ^/budget/(.*)$ /budget/index.php/$1 last;
}
```

But I'm not sure how this would translate to Apache? It looks like I will need a `mod_rewrite` rule in the `.htaccess` file?